# Какие есть утилиты для тестирования Си программ под разные конфигурации железа?

Tags: c, тестирование, виртуальная-машина, виртуализация

Появилась необходимость посмотреть, как поведет себя программа (Си, без сторонних библиотек) на слабых устройствах. Мне достаточно иметь возможность ограничить объем памяти и тактовую частоту ЦП. Есть альтернатива удобнее VirtualBox?

Comment: а какая ОС будет использоваться?